# How do I Invoke a Generic Method with Specific Type Parameters?

Tags: java, generics

I have a method with the following signature:

```
<T> T getBody(Class<T> type)
```

that returns the body object as the specified type. How do I invoke it to return an object of type

```
Iterable<OProperty<?>>
```

I did a lot of Java before generics so my programmer fu is a little rusty in these circumstances :)

Answer (score 5):

This can't be done with `Class<T>`.  The only allowed `T` is a raw type because that is all that `Class` can be parametrized with (you can have `Class<List>` but not `Class<List<String>>`).

Comment: of course you can: `(Class<List<String>>)(Class<?>)List.class`

Answer (score 0):

`Class` and generics doesn't work together very well. `Class` is for representing concrete runtime types, while generics is at compile time. We would like to have `Class<Iterable>` and `Class<Iterable<Something>>`, etc., but at runtime there is only one such object. No type for it would fit all of these uses. Java chose `Class<Iterable>`.

You can use some dubious unchecked casts to get the right type to pass to it:

`getBody(Class<Iterable<OProperty<?>>>)(Class<?>)Iterable.class)`